# how to disable right-click on google forms

Tags: javascript, right-click

I am creating a quiz on google form. In order to restrict participants from copying questions, I wish to disable the right-click button on the form. kindly elaborate as to how it can be done. Also, I am a novice at javascripting, detailed answers in laymen language would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that preventing copying will never be 100% effective. Users can printscreen, save the web page, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this (jQuery though)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pdukvm2g/) - Right click text Test to try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false"> //This should disable the context menu (right click)
</body>
```

Or with JS

```
<script language="javascript">
    document.onmousedown=disableclick;
    Function disableclick(event)
    {
      if(event.button==2) //Right Button
       {
         return false;    
       }
    }
</script>
```

Please note that this can be bypassed since some browsers allow the user to use the right click button even if it's disabled by JS..